# Cannot #include <string> in Visual Studio 2010 without many errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and am trying to

```
#include <string>
```

in a C++ configured project. However, I get over 100 errors when I try to do so, as shown at the bottom of this post. I also tried including algorithm, iostream, and map to see if I got the same results (and I did), which leads me to believe it may have something to do with the STL or including anything other than .h files. I noticed that there are already STL files within the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\
```

directory. By trying to use strings, am I somehow interfering with some kind of preset VS STL? Or is this some other issue?

I also tried getting the source code for the STL and putting it in a folder in the same directory as my .cpp file to reference it there but then I ran into a host of problems with the includes within the STL files. Any ideas?

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(436): error C2371: 'ptrdiff_t' : redefinition; different basic types 1>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stddef.h(26) : see declaration of
>   'ptrdiff_t' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(32): error C2039: 'lldiv_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(32): error C2873: 'lldiv_t' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(34): error
>   C2039: 'llabs' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(34): error
>   C2873: 'llabs' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(34): error C2039: 'lldiv' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cstdlib(34): error C2873: 'lldiv' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\malloc.h(104): error C2375: 'calloc' :
>   redefinition; different linkage 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdlib.h(89) : see declaration of
>   'calloc' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\malloc.h(105): error C2375: 'free' : redefinition; different linkage 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdlib.h(90) : see declaration of
>   'free' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\malloc.h(106): error C2375: 'malloc' : redefinition; different linkage 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdlib.h(91) : see declaration of
>   'malloc' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\malloc.h(108): error C2375: 'realloc' : redefinition; different linkage 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdlib.h(92) : see declaration of
>   'realloc' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\malloc.h(236): error C3861: 'free': identifier not found 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(55): error C2371: '_iobuf' : redefinition; different basic types 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cstdio(34) : see declaration of '_iobuf'
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(65): error C2371: 'FILE' : redefinition; different basic types 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdio.h(133) : see declaration of
>   'FILE' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(76): warning C4005: 'stdin' : macro redefinition 1>          c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdio.h(146)
>   : see previous definition of 'stdin' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(77): warning
>   C4005: 'stdout' : macro redefinition 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdio.h(147) : see previous
>   definition of 'stdout' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(78): warning C4005: 'stderr' : macro
>   redefinition 1>          c:\cats\executive\common_include\stdio.h(148)
>   : see previous definition of 'stderr' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(1110): error
>   C2011: 'tm' : 'struct' type redefinition 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\time.h(69) : see declaration of 'tm'
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\wtime.inl(48): error C2664: '_wctime64' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time64_t *' 1>
>
>   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
>   C-style cast or function-style cast 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\wtime.inl(54): error C2664: 'errno_t
>   _wctime64_s(wchar_t *,size_t,const __time64_t *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const time_t *' to 'const __time64_t *' 1>
>
>   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
>   C-style cast or function-style cast 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(1187): error C2375: 'memmove' :
>   redefinition; different linkage 1>
>
>   c:\cats\executive\common_include\string.h(35) : see declaration of
>   'memmove' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\wchar.h(1223): error C3861: 'memmove': identifier not found 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'acosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2873: 'acosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2039: 'asinf' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2873: 'asinf' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2039:
>   'atanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2873:
>   'atanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error
>   C2039: 'atan2f' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error
>   C2873: 'atan2f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2039: 'ceilf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(20): error C2873: 'ceilf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(21): error C2039: 'cosf' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(21): error C2873: 'cosf' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(21): error C2039:
>   'coshf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(21): error C2873:
>   'coshf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(21): error
>   C2039: 'expf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(21): error
>   C2873: 'expf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(22): error C2039: 'fabsf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(22): error C2873: 'fabsf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(22): error C2039: 'floorf' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(22): error C2873: 'floorf' :
>   symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(22): error C2039:
>   'fmodf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(22): error C2873:
>   'fmodf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error
>   C2039: 'frexpf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error
>   C2873: 'frexpf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2039: 'ldexpf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2873: 'ldexpf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2039: 'logf' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(23): error C2873: 'logf' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2039:
>   'log10f' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2873:
>   'log10f' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error
>   C2039: 'modff' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error
>   C2873: 'modff' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2039: 'powf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(24): error C2873: 'powf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2039: 'sinf' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2873: 'sinf' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2039:
>   'sinhf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error C2873:
>   'sinhf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error
>   C2039: 'sqrtf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(25): error
>   C2873: 'sqrtf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2039: 'tanf' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2873: 'tanf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2039: 'tanhf' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(26): error C2873: 'tanhf' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2039:
>   'acosl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2873:
>   'acosl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error
>   C2039: 'asinl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error
>   C2873: 'asinl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2039: 'atanl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2873: 'atanl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2039: 'atan2l' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2873: 'atan2l' :
>   symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2039:
>   'ceill' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2873:
>   'ceill' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error
>   C2039: 'cosl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error
>   C2873: 'cosl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2039: 'coshl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2873: 'coshl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2039: 'expl' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2873: 'expl' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2039:
>   'fabsl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2873:
>   'fabsl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error
>   C2039: 'floorl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error
>   C2873: 'floorl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2039: 'fmodl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2873: 'fmodl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2039: 'frexpl' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2873: 'frexpl' :
>   symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2039:
>   'ldexpl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2873:
>   'ldexpl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error
>   C2039: 'logl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error
>   C2873: 'logl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'log10l' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'log10l' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2039: 'modfl' : is not a
>   member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2873: 'modfl' : symbol
>   cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2039:
>   'powl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2873:
>   'powl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error
>   C2039: 'sinl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error
>   C2873: 'sinl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>   1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2039: 'sinhl' : is not a member of '`global namespace'' 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2873: 'sinhl' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(34): fatal error C1003: error count
>   exceeds 100; stopping compilation
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I mean, it's *obviously* not a compiler bug, and moving Standard Library files around willy-nilly isn't going to help.

Comment: If you're attempting to  use a 3rd-part STL (such as stlports) you should consider putting its include folder *ahead* of the regular include path. Honestly I don't advise using a 3rd party port regardless. The one shipped with vs2010 is more than adequate. If you're *not* trying to use a 3rd party standard lib and this is exhibiting with the vs2010 std lib implementation, you have have accidentally dorked your default include config in some past (or current) project.

Answer (score 1):

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\crtdefs.h(436): error C2371: 'ptrdiff_t' : redefinition; different basic types

Most likely this is a problem with how you have configured your project.

The first thing I would check is to make sure you have `WIN64` defined (and `WIN32` *not* defined) in your project settings.

Comment: So here's more info that will make it more complicated. I'm constructing the project on a PC I've remoted into that is an Intel Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 - i.e. runs Windows 7 and is 64 bit - but the CPU I'll be using the .dll I build is running off a Celeron(R) CPU - i.e. runs XP and is 32 bit.

I also checked the project settings and it is indeed configured on an Active(Win32) platform. However, there is no Win64 option. Is this the right place to look?